# I can't install anything on my PC because of an error

Tags: 13.10, 64-bit

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Read error - read (5: Input/output error)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

This is what I get when I try to install anything in terminal and the software center won't load. I installed Windows XP Pro so I could use itunes yesterday and it freezes, I dual booted Ubuntu with XP and I can't install anything, I also can't use my sound card and I had to use the onboard sound card built into my motherboard.

Comment: try "df -Th " and tell if you got any error. and Also, can you run a disk check on that drive (or partition depending on what you've got) to make sure there's nothing wrong. as it could be a issue if having bad sector on hard drive.

Comment: For checking the drive, an easy way is to use GParted - you may need to back up your data first, but it sounds like your computer needs backing up anyway...  . For the sound card, look at `lspci` or `lshw -C multimedia`, and then add your sound card model (and driver - if any) to your question.

Comment: Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1      ext4      106G  4.1G   96G   5% /
none           tmpfs     4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev           devtmpfs  1.5G  4.0K  1.5G   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     300M  1.3M  299M   1% /run
none           tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs     1.5G  232K  1.5G   1% /run/shm
none           tmpfs     100M   72K  100M   1% /run/user - This is what I got for typing df-Th in terminal

Comment: Thanks wilf! I was going to open my PC after it cooled down to pull out the sound card and find out what it is, but this command told me what it was.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem and I reinstalled Ubuntu and that seemed to work out just fine, maybe you should reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: I have done that a long time ago, thanks for your answer. It works fine